# Textbox is not writing the first letter every time I open the appliction

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm conditioning some textboxs in a c# windows form app, like, making every letter uppercase, or disabling the special characters, etc.

But every time I open this app and try to write something in one of those textbox, the very first letter does not appear, as if I had never written anything. After that, I can use it normally (with all the conditions).

```
private void TxbDGVFilter_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            txbDGVFilter.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
            if (!(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)) && !(Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar)) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No special characters allowed!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: try with keydown event

Comment: Try using the `KeyUp` event instead.

Comment: You should handle the Key Down event insted of Key Press

Comment: i tried with the KeyDown event, but it was the same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
txbDGVFilter.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```

This code should be run at constructor.